# Given a sentence in english with a blank space, how can I estmate in python the probability of a specific word to fit into that blank space?

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, word-embedding

Let's say we have a sentence in python3 with a blank space like the following:

`sentence = "Tomorrow I want to go _______."`

and we want to find out which word is more likely to appear in the blank space from a pool of words:

`pool_of_words = ['eating', 'playing', 'thinking', 'jogging']`

**Question: How can I estimate the probability of each word from the pool to appear in that blank space?**

**Example:**
I guess the solution could be in the shape of a probability function that would give something like the examples below. How can I build such a function?

`probability('jogging') = 0.98`

`probability('eating') = 0.81`

`probability('thinking') = 0.2`

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I guess you yourself answered your question :(

Comment: I dont know how to implement that. Perhaps the question should be: 
How can I implement such a function? Or which python libraries do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

You should read up on language models. There are different approaches to this problem, starting from simple n-gram models, where you count the number of occurrences of word sequences in a corpus and then estimate the likelihood of the next word based on the distribution you found in your corpus. You can also solve this with neural networks of different complexity, which I assume might be a bit difficult for a beginner.

Check out this article, it contains sample code in python for both approaches.

“A Comprehensive Guide to Build your own Language Model in Python!” by Mohd Sanad Zaki Rizvi https://link.medium.com/s7zzcsKie2

Comment: This article was very enlightning. Thank you so much!